# How to set up Dell OMSA tools on Debian 6 (Squeeze) (PE2950)

Tags: dell-poweredge, debian-squeeze, dell-openmanage

I assume I have set up them up incorrectly or am missing a library or dependency. When I log into the OMSA web interface I can't see anything [image: omsa]

Also, `omreport` tells me nothing;

```
root@box:~# omreport storage controller
No controllers found
```

I assume these two will use the same source of information so what ever is wrong will fix them both.

I set up OMSA as per [these](http://keithscode.com/tutorials/linux/18-installing-dell-openmanage-server-administrator-on-ubuntu.html) instructions.

Also I have compiled MegaCLI (as this is a PowerEdge 2950 with a Perc 6/i controller) and I have used that to update the RAID firmware, so that works, but the Dell tools aren't.

What have I missed during set up?

```
root@box:~# cat /etc/issue
Debian GNU/Linux 6.0 \n \l

root@box:~# uname -a
Linux box 3.4.9 #1 SMP Wed Aug 22 19:08:46 BST 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I have done under Debian 6 x86_64, Kernel 3.4.9, to get OMSA working although the storage controller isn't showing up. I have MegaCLI working now which is a better in my opinion so I am happy with this;

```
# Kernel modules
sudo modprobe ipmi_msghandler
sudo modprobe ipmi_devintf
sudo modprobe ipmi_s
# Sometimes this is `sudo modprobe ipmi_si` on 64bit machines

sudo -i
echo "ipmi_msghandler" >> /etc/modules
echo "ipmi_devintf" >> /etc/modules
echo "ipmi_si" >> /etc/modules
exit

# To use a repo stop here and perform add to /etc/apt/sources.list
# "deb ftp://ftp.sara.nl/pub/sara-omsa dell sara"
# then run;
# wget http://ftp.sara.nl/debian_sara.asc
# sudo apt-key add debian_sara.asc
# sudo apt-get update 
# Now there is no need to download the debian packages below


#Install IPMI tools;
sudo apt-get install openipmi
sudo apt-get install ipmitool

#Install OMSA dependancies:
sudo apt-get install snmp snmpd 
sudo apt-get install -f lib32ncurses5
#sudo apt-get install -f libncurses5 # Not needed on 64 bit machine
sudo apt-get install -f ia32-libs #Only needed for 64bit machines

# If not use the deb packages below but the repo above, at this point you can execute;
# sudo apt-get install dellomsa 

#Grab OMSA and debian package (can be http): ONLY IF NOT USING REPO ABOVE
#wget ftp://ftp.sara.nl/pub/outgoing/dell/binary-i386/dellomsa_5.5.0-5_i386.deb
wget ftp://ftp.sara.nl/pub/outgoing/dell/binary-amd64/dellomsa_5.5.0-5_amd64.deb
# mirrors:
# http://www.jamesbensley.co.cc/uploads/linux/dell/dellomsa_5.5.0-5_i386.deb
# http://www.jamesbensley.co.cc/uploads/linux/dell/dellomsa_5.5.0-5_amd64.deb
dpkg -i dellomsa_5.5.0-5_amd64.deb

#At this point, run the following to update libraries when using either repo or deb pkg
sudo ldconfig

#For 32bit machine with library/dependencies missing;
sudo apt-get install libstdc++5
#May require gcc.3.3 to get the right version: sudo apt-get install gcc-3.3-base

#For 64 bit machine we may need 32bit libstdc++5 from here, forced install on 64 bit machine:
wget http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gcc-3.3/libstdc++5_3.3.6-20_i386.deb
# http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gcc-3.3/libstdc++5_3.3.6-20_amd64.deb
# Mirrors;
# http://www.jamesbensley.co.cc/uploads/linux/dell/libstdc++5_3.3.6-20_i386.deb
# http://www.jamesbensley.co.cc/uploads/linux/dell/libstdc++5_3.3.6-20_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg --force-architecture -i libstdc++5_3.3.6-20_i386.deb

#Some links maybe needed: 
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.5 /lib/libstdc++.so.5
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.5 /lib32/libstdc++.so.5
#sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.5 /lib64/libstdc++.so.5 # This should exist on 64-bit machine

#Pop this handy script into /etc/init.d (Thanks to James Kyle) and run it
sudo wget -O /etc/init.d/dell_omsa.sh http://www.jamesbensley.co.cc/uploads/linux/dell/dell_omsa.sh
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/dell_omsa.sh
sudo /etc/init.d/dell_omsa.sh

# Enable SNMP in OMSA
sudo /etc/init.d/dataeng enablesnmp
# Make sure both are running
sudo /etc/init.d/snmpd restart
sudo /etc/init.d/dataeng start
sudo /etc/init.d/dsm_om_connsvc start
sudo /etc/init.d/dsm_om_shrsvc start

# To log into OMSA with a local user accout;
# Download 32bit pam auth modules if on 64 (also, force inet4 sometimes):
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/p/pam/libpam-modules_1.1.3-2ubuntu1_i386.deb --inet4-only
# Newer versions:
# http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/p/pam/libpam-modules_1.1.3-6ubuntu1_amd64.deb
# http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/p/pam/libpam-modules_1.1.3-6ubuntu1_i386.deb
dpkg-deb -x libpam-modules_1.1.3-2ubuntu1_i386.deb ./
cd ./lib/i386-linux-gnu/security
sudo cp pam_unix.so /lib32/security
sudo cp pam_nologin.so /lib32/security
sudo ldconfig 

#Restart 
sudo /etc/init.d/dsm_om_connsvc restart
#OMSA seems to bind to a TCP socket on IPv6, as shown by netstat -nl, check in /opt/dell/srvadmin/iws/config/iws.ini
# tcp6 :::1311
# But this will accept connectios on any local IPV4 address or IPv6 address
#browser: https://[2a01:420:9:0:213:72ff:fe53:2c05]:1311
#or: https://10.0.25.76:1311

# MegaRAID/CLI stuff for LSI Controllers in Dells (Perc's like 5/i and 6/i etc)

# might need the following if not installed
sudo apt-get install alien unzip sysfsutils

#Download link
wget http://www.lsi.com/downloads/Public/MegaRAID%20Common%20Files/8.02.16_MegaCLI.zip
# mirror:
# http://www.jamesbensley.co.cc/uploads/linux/dell/8.02.16_MegaCLI.zip
unzip 8.02.16_MegaCLI.zip
cd LINUX
unzip MegaCliLin.zip
# Install the bundled libraries;
sudo alien -iv Lib_Utils-1.00-09.noarch.rpm

# Upack;
rpm2cpio MegaCli-8.02.16-1.i386.rpm | cpio -dimv

# copy files to /opt
sudo mv opt/MegaRAID/ /opt/
cd /opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli/
sudo ./MegaCli -AdpEventLog -GetEvents -aAll

# Example commands:
# http://tools.rapidsoft.de/perc/perc-cheat-sheet.html

# Controller information
MegaCli -AdpAllInfo -aALL
```

Answer (score 1):

You might try to follow the steps at

https://linux.dell.com/repo/community/deb/latest/

to install the latest version. Works for me on recent machines (R620, R720), but I didn't test it on 3.4 kernels yet...

Comment: I know of this site, but it likely won't work installing the newest OMSA on PE2950, the hardware is too old for the latest OMSA and has compatibility issues (some features don't work). This was more of an exercise in matching the OMSA version to the hardware version, not the OS version (although we can't rule out that the OS version will play some part in it!)